# how can I download the model file watson concept insight uses?

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using Watson API to do some concept annotations.
I'd like to then run word2vec on the returned concepts so I can then measure the distances / similarity between concepts. For that I need to work against the same model. Where can I download the model file watson is using [here](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/concept-insights-v2)?

To be more precise I'm using the default one which is wikipedia/en-20120601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't download the models. That part of the service is not exposed.